# How to plot the median and interquartile range of data that is already sorted by row in R?

Tags: r, row, median

My data frame is arrange the following way

```
time run1 run2 run3 run4 run5
0    2.0  3.0  3.5  4.0  2.0
1    1.5  2.5  4.5  6.5  2.5
2    [...]
[...]
```

I want to plot the median of the run values at each point in time. 
I tried to use stat_summary in ggplot but I dont know how to define the input for several y's(run1,run2,run3...) per x(timestep). And I am also not sure how to reformat the data best to avoid using it by row.

//Edit: Thanks for the help

```
library(reshape)
plotsmelt = melt(plots, id="time")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotsmelt,aes(x=time,y=value)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data=median_hilow)
```

This code did the first part. Now my graph looks like this:
[(current graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmRVA.png)
Can I reshape it to a smoothed/fitted line with interquartiles only at certain intervals like this:
[(desired format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4scYL.jpg)

//Edit2: Thanks again! now I have the interquartiles at the right intervals. Now I only need a way to show a fitted/smoothed curve through the median datapoints and my graph is done.

Edit3: Case solved by user127649. thanks I actually sat some hours on trying to figure this out searching google before you helped me!

Comment: `plot(df$time, apply(df[-1], 1 median))` will do it in base R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot median and IQR, it sounds like you're trying to do a boxplot?

First you should rearrange your data

```
library(reshape)
data.m <- melt(data)
```

Then to plot it in ggplot

```
ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, value)
    geom_boxplot()
```

**Edit #1**

This might be a bit rough but something along these lines should get the IQR at desired intervals. I think you need to add the medians and IQR in separate layers:

```
ggplot(data.m,aes(x = time, y = value)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y = "median", geom = "point") +
     stat_summary(data = data.m[data.m$time %% 10 == 0, ], colour = fun.data = median_hilow)
```

Obviously, you should change `data.m[data.m$time %% 10 == 0, ]` to the interval you require

**Edit #2**

To add a fitted line:

```
 + geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

see `?geom_smooth` for further options